# assign enum in switch case in c#

Tags: c#, enums

I need to change my Enum in switch case statement like below

```
var en; 
switch (RequestTypID.ToString())
            {
                case "15":
                    en = enum1;
                    break;
                case "16":
                    en = enum2;
                    break;
                case "14":
                    en = enum3;
                    break;
                case "13":
                    en = enum4;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

and then pas it to a foreach loop like this

```
foreach (var status in Enum.GetValues(typeof(en)))
```

i`m geeting an error that says en must be initialize ?
what type should i declare for en variable ?
what type should i declare for status variable ?

alright i`ve added this line to the code and one problem is solved;

```
var en = typeof(enum1);
```

but now it say it cant find en reference in my for each loop ?

i also change my switch case to something like this

```
switch (RequestTypID.ToString())
            {
                case "15":
                    en = typeof(enum1);
                    break; 
                    ....
```

Comment: What is enum1,enum2,enum3?

Comment: these are my 3 enumurators that i need to use them for controling the flow of a request that passes between different  users. and they are in the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enum.GetValues` require a Type as parameter. So simply declare you `en` as `Type`.

```
Type en = null;
```

you cannot declare it as `var` without initializing it: compiler need to know what is the real type you want to use.

also, you have to change in your switch:

```
en = typeof(SomeEnum);
```

Comment: i also had to change the for each to     foreach (var status in Enum.GetValues(en)) becuase en is now a type and don`t need to call gettype() .

Answer (score 1):

> i`m geeting an error that says en must be initialize ?

This is reasonable, because this `var en;` is not correct. When we want to declare something implicitly, we have to assign a value to it, when we declare it, in order the compiler infer it's type.

For instance, `var n = 4;`. The `4` can be stored to a variable of type `int`. Hence the compiler, when see this declaration understands that the tyoe of n int.

Comment: i tried system.enum but it say it can`t convert myenum(`s) to that .

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an variable with `var`(`var` isn't a type) and not assign a value to it.`Var` means that compiler will evaluate it's `type` seeing it's value, but here you don't have a value of the variable.So you need to assign a value to your variable `en`.Assign a value which type is **enum1, enum2, enum3, enum4**..

Answer (score 1):

You have to have another variable to the right side of the `var` statement so the compile know what to expect.

You should do the following:

```
var en = YourEnum.Option1;
```

or

```
YourEnum en;
```